# $\{f_n\} \in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$, converges pointwise to $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$. Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f_n \, dx = \int_a^b f \, dx$.

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:**

> Suppose $f_n$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of functions, in $\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ which converges pointwise to a function $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$. Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f_n \, dx = \int_a^b f \, dx$.

The answer, I believe, should look very similar to the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) or it's immediately corollary, the [bounded convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Bounded_convergence_theorem). Is there a simpler way to prove the above, that does not use these results from measure theory?

Comment: It suffices to show that if $g_n \geq 0$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of non-negative functions in $\mathcal R[a,b]$ converging pointwise to $0$, then the limit of their integrals is zero.  That being said, I'm not sure how to prove this (without measure theory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as Arzela's bounded convergence theorem. Here are some references with history and proofs.

1. W. A. J. Luxemburg Arzela's Dominated Convergence Theorem for the
   Riemann Integral, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 78, No. 9
   (Nov., 1971), pp. 970-979 http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317801
2. Nadish de Silva, A CONCISE, ELEMENTARY PROOF OF ARZELÀ'S BOUNDED
   CONVERGENCE THEOREM http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.1439.pdf

Comment: That second article is fascinating! Thank you!