# Is there any function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that it has right derivative but not left derivative at every point?

Tags: calculus

Is there any function $$f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$$ such that it has right derivative but not left derivative at every point?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? What is the context of this problem? It reads remarkably similar to the last one that was answered here.

Comment: not that similar in my very own very humble very opinion

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135811/for-a-function-which-is-everywhere-right-differentiable-what-can-be-said-about) seems relevant.

Comment: First one was easier than this. I thought same in the answer but couldnt be sure.  I also wonder what people think about them. I am learning in basic. These are good for me. But for this one, it's seen that there is no such function. But this is not mathematical.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q_1,q_2,\ldots$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$, and

$$ f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}1 & \text{if }  x\geq q_n,\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{array}\right.$$
If we consider 
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n}\,f_n(x) $$
then $f(x)$ has a right derivative for every $x\in[0,1]$ but no left derivative exists if $x\in\mathbb{Q}\in[0,1]$.

Now we may try to condensate singularities, but due to [Denjoy-Young-Saks theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Saks_theorem), we cannot achieve the non-existence of the left derivative over a subset of $[0,1]$ with positive measure.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Saks_theorem) (as noted in my link above), you won't get positive measure. I wonder if you can get uncountable.